# Uniform initialization of references

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, reference, uniform-initialization

I am currently trying to understand the new uniform initialization of C++0x. Unfortunately, I stumpled over using uniform initialization of references. Example:

```
int main() {
   int a;
   int &ref{a};
}
```

This example works fine:

```
% LANG=C g++ uniform_init_of_ref.cpp -std=c++0x -o uni -Wall -Wextra
uniform_init_of_ref.cpp: In function `int main()':
uniform_init_of_ref.cpp:3:10: warning: unused variable `ref' [-Wunused-variable]
```

(**Update** Comeau throws an error for that example, so maybe gcc shouldn't compile it as well)

Now, if I use a custom data type instead of an integer, it doesn't work anymore:

```
class Y
{};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    Y &ref{y};
}

% LANG=C g++ initialization.cpp -std=c++0x -o initialization -Wall -Wextra
initialization.cpp: In function `int main()':
initialization.cpp:9:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `Y&' from an rvalue of type `<brace-enclosed initializer list>'
initialization.cpp:9:8: warning: unused variable `ref' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find the relevant section in the standard draft. My guess is that I am misunderstanding the usage of uniform initialization, as Comeau complains with this message:

```
ComeauTest.c(9): error: reference variable "ref" requires an initializer
      Y &ref{y};
```

**So, can someone of you point me in the right direction?**

---

In case that you want to know why this question is relevant and why I don't just use `Y &ref(y)`: I'd like to be able to use uniform initialization in the initialization list of a constructor:

```
class X { };

class Y {
    const X& x;

    public:
        Y (const X& xx):
            x{xx}
        {}
};

int main () {
    X x;
    Y y{x};
}
```

This fails with the same error message as above.

Note:

- I am using `LANG=C` to enable english error messages.
- gcc version: 4.6.1

Comment: gcc 4.4.1 does not compile the first example either: `uniform_init_of_ref.cpp:3: error: ISO C++ forbids use of initializer list to initialize referen
ce 'ref'`

Comment: @rmflow: gcc4.4 does not fully implement uniform initialization.

Comment: You can use the ordinary `x(xx)` in your constructor initializer list, as far as I can see no need for that newfangled uniform stuff :-)

Comment: @alf-p-steinbach Yes, but I wanted to avoid that to use the same style of initialization in a constructor without changing style depending on what has to be initialized.

Comment: Maybe it's just a bug. It's not like C++0x support in GCC has been tested for many years or anything.

Comment: @nicolas-bolas Yes, it could be a bug. Comeau also complains about the first example using `int &ref{a}`.

Comment: @evnu: Actually I believe it is correct to complain, because if I read N2672 correctly, lvalue references to non-const objects should not be allowed to be initialized this way, no matter whether they are primitive or class types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [N2672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm) the paragraph 8.5.4.4 should say:

> Otherwise, if T is a reference type, an rvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to that temporary. [ Note: As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. ]

which (if I understand it correctly) means uniform initialization of references binds them to new anonymous instances, so it seems to me it's pretty useless. That still does not explain why one works and the other does not; they should behave the same (unless `Y` has some explicit constructors).

Comment: So in the first example, doing `ref = 42` will **not** modify `a`.

Comment: @alexandre-c assigning to `ref` in the first example changes the value of `a` here.

Comment: @evnu: this behaviour is not conform to what @Jan quotes. Did you check with Comeau ?

Comment: @alexandre-c Comeau throws an error on the first example. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what n3290 does say, except it uses *prvalue temporary* instead of *rvalue temporary*.