# Initialization of const reference member in initializer list

Tags: c++, gcc, reference, initialization, initializer-list

I was playing with some useless code to understand initialization of member references, and bumped into this:

```
struct A {};

struct B
{
    B() : a()
    {
    }

    const A& a;
};
```

The code above gives the following error when compiled with gcc 4.9.2:

```
In constructor 'B::B()':
error: value-initialization of reference type 'const A&'
  B() : a()
```

Which I understand.

But if I use uniform initialization in B's constructor's initializer list, like so:

```
struct A {};

struct B
{
    B() : a{}
    {
    }

    const A& a;
};
```

It compiles fine.

So the question is, why does the use of uniform initialization here change the compilation result?

I also tried this with Microsoft Visual C++ 2013.
It does not compile either version of the code, with the same error message:

```
Error 3 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const A &
```

You can have a quick play with it here:

http://ideone.com/7f2t8I

Comment: Uniform initialization is a relatively new feature, and you have to expect some compiler bugs with it.  In this case, without looking it up, I'd guess  that the Microsoft compiler is correct.

Comment: My guess: `{}` is interpreted as a call to the default constructor of `A` (like if you did `A a {};`), so a temporary `A{}` is created. It is then bound to the const-ref and its lifetime is extended (like if you did `const A & a {}`, which also works in GCC). But I don't know what the standard says about that; if it is allowed... What really confuses me is that MSVC sees an `int` which I cannot see... Did you really compile this code?

Comment: @JamesKanze I understand that, but I didn't want to just go out and shout compiler bug. Maybe there is something about uniform initialization that I don't know and that would make it behave differently in this situation.

Comment: @leemes MSVC often uses default ints in its error messages. I have no idea whether this is one of those cases though.

Comment: @leemes GCC indeed calls the default constructor and binds the result to the `const` reference.  At least, it does so when I add a data member to `A` that I set in `A`'s default constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546470/uniform-initialization-of-references seems it is allowed by the standard, but the result is kinda useless and probably dangerous because the object is gone but the reference will still be there.

Comment: @thang A temporary bound to a `const` reference will live as long as the reference it is bound to.

Comment: @leemes Yes, I did really compile this code. You guess is the same as mine as to why it works with uniform initialization. Having said that, I would expect it not to work, because 'a' is not an A, is a const A&.

Comment: @5gon12eder, that's what I thought until I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary.  see the quote from the standard that says: **A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (§12.6.2 [class.base.init]) persists until the constructor exits**.  Not exactly sure how to interpret that.

Comment: @thang It was a defect in the standard that has been fixed ([I was told](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25561387/1392132)).

Comment: @5gon12eder, that link has nothing about when the standard was fixed.  It's just a gcc implementation issue.  Do you know when the standard was changed with respect to this issue?  Also,in the bug report, someone says "G++ is actually correct according to wording in the C++11 FDIS (see 8.5.4 paragraphs 5 and 6)".  I think that is correct.  I think the warning is right.  You are allowed to do it, but it is dangerous, unless the standard has changed.  I am very interested in when that happened... I ran into this problem before.

Comment: @thang See  Jonathan Wakely's comment to the accepted answer. However, as I think about it, I'm not exactly sure that this is the same rule that applies here.

Comment: @Hugo If two compilers do different things, and it's not unspecified, implementation dependent, or undefined behavior, one has a bug.  Unless, which is possibly the case here, they are implementing different versions of the standard; one of the answers suggests that there is a change in C++14 which affects the legality of the second version.

Comment: @5gon12eder, DR 1288 seems to be only marginally related.  It doesn't address the constructor initialization (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288).

Comment: @5gon12eder The standard used to say that list-initialization for references always created a temporary and never did direct binding. That is the cause of the GCC problem in the linked question (it makes no sense to create a temporary when the reference can be bound directly) and was fixed by CWG1288. The temporary lifetime issue is distinct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC is correct in its interpretation of `{}`. [dcl.init.list]/p3.8-9 (quoting N4296; earlier drafts has the same relative ordering of these two bullets):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as
>   follows:
>
> - [7 inapplicable bullets omitted]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is copy-list-initialized or
>     direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for
>     the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary. [ *Note*:
>     As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the
>     reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. —*end note*
>     ]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

List-initializing the reference hits bullet 3.8, causing the construction of a temporary. The value-initialization case, in 3.9, doesn't apply.

Value-initialization of a reference is ill-formed ([dcl.init]/p9):

> A program that calls for default-initialization or
>   value-initialization of an entity of reference type is ill-formed.

---

However, as of N4296, per [class.base.init]/p8:

> A temporary expression bound to a reference member in a
>   *mem-initializer* is ill-formed.

This was added as a result of [CWG issue 1696](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4305.html#1696), which is a DR (defect report) against C++14.

Pre-CWG1696, the standard provided that (N4140 [class.temporary]/p5.1):

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s
>   *ctor-initializer* (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.

which means that the reference will become dangling immediately after construction. This presumably motivated CWG1696's decision to disallow such bindings altogether.

Comment: I assume N4296 is C++14.  So they've finally corrected something which has been a problem (IMHO) since C++98.

Comment: @JamesKanze N4140 is C++14. CWG 1696 is a DR against C++14, however, so should still be implemented by compilers in C++14 mode.

Comment: Does any compiler have a fully compliant C++14 mode?  (For that matter, does any have a fully compliant C++11 mode?)

Comment: @JamesKanze and T.C. Thank you both for you comments and answers. I appreciate the difference between the two kinds of initialization in question now. From this answer I am also lead to believe that gcc 4.9.2 is not compliant with the standard regarding N4296 [class.base.init]/p8.

Comment: @Hugo That was just added last November :)

Comment: @Hugo Regarding non-compliance: it may just be an issue of the compilers targetting different versions of the standard.  (And since T.C.s answer now covers everything I mentionned in my, and is far more complete and accurate, I'll delete mine.)